# How to disable certain user rsa certificate in OpenVPN?

Tags: linux, openvpn, rsa

Suppose we create certificates for OpenVPN using `easy-rsa`. And we have two clients - client1 and client2 with their certificates etc. Suppose that some time later we need to disable client2 certificate as `he is a bad guy`. How to do it?

Comment: Just revoke it and start OpenVPN with the updated CRL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To elaborate Michael Hampton's comment, here's how you do it:

> 1. cd /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa
> 2. . ./vars
> 3. ./revoke-full client2.crt
> 4. mv -v /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/crl.pem /etc/openvpn/
> 5. cat /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/index.txt
> 6. Make sure you see something like this: R   111111111117Z   111111111111Z   01
>      unknown/C=PH/ST=NCR/L=MC/O=Company/OU=IT/CN=client2/name=client2/emailAddress=client2@company.com
> 7. vi /etc/openvpn/server.conf
> 8. Make sure you have this "crl-verify crl.pem"
> 9. Save and exit
> 10. Restart OpenVPN service